# How to dynamically create streamlit forms

Tags: python, json, streamlit

I was trying to create stream lit dashboard using a JSON file bu i was getting error. Is it possible to create dashboard from JSON data and dynamically render streamlit form.

```
JSON_FILE = '''{
    "project": "Prediction",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "name":"Prediction Dashboard",
            "inputs": "Sol d", 
            "inputs_two":"Sol d",
            
            "desc":{
                "Solute_Smile": "Solute Sequence",
                "Solvent_smile": "Solvent Sequence",
                "Probability_Score": "(in Kcal/mol) :"
            }
        }
    ]
}'''

def load_data(data):
    data = json.loads(data)
    return data

data  = load_data(JSON_FILE)

for i in range(len(data['tasks'])):
  title = st.title(data['tasks'][i]['name'])
  form = st.form(key="form_one")
  input = form.text_input(label =  st.title(data['tasks'][i]['inputs']))
  input_two = form.text_input(label = st.title(data['tasks'][i]['inputs_two']))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 text_input(), you need to define a unique key. You also need a submit button. Also your label should be in text form and not st.title()

When you have more items to loop over, you need a unique form key too. See example below.

###### Code

```
for i in range(len(data['tasks'])):
    title = st.title(data['tasks'][i]['name'])
    form = st.form(key=f"form_one_{i}")
    input = form.text_input(label=f"{data['tasks'][i]['inputs']}", key=f"input1_{i}")
    input_two = form.text_input(label=f"{data['tasks'][i]['inputs_two']}", key=f"input2_{i}")
    form.form_submit_button()
```

###### Output

[image]

###### References

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.text_input